# Convert pandas DataFrame to HTML and then show in email

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, email

I have a script that gives me a table in a DataFrame. I then convert it to HTML and send it in an email.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import smtplib
from IPython.display import HTML

def sendEmail():
    sender = 'DanielScript@domain.com'
    receivers = ['daniel@domain.com']
    message = """From: Daniel's Script <DanielScript@domain.com>
    To: Anyone who forgot
    Subject: New Employees Reminder

    Hi, here is a list of the people who will start working here soon: \n**{}** \n\nYou're welcome\nDaniel Beiin
    """.format(df)
    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtpserver')
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender , receivers, message)         
        print("Successfully sent email")
    except SMTPException:
        print ("Error: unable to send email")

df = pd.read_csv(r'testcsv.csv')
df = HTML(df.to_html())

sendEmail()
```

Problem is, I get `**<IPython.core.display.HTML object>**` in the email itself.
I'm not sure how to present it. I don't want to attach the file to the email, I want the table to appear formatted as HTML when someone opens the email.

I'm not sure how to do so.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried not wrapping the output of `to_html()` with the `IPython.display.HTML` method? Pandas' `to_html` already outputs the desired string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Daniel,
Just try this modification in your code.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt
    import smtplib
    import codecs
    from IPython.display import HTML

    def sendEmail():
    sender = 'DanielScript@domain.com'
    receivers = ['daniel@domain.com']
    message = """From: Daniel's Script <DanielScript@domain.com>
    To: Anyone who forgot
    Subject: New Employees Reminder

    Hi, here is a list of the people who will start working here soon: \n**{}** 
    \n\nYou're welcome\nDaniel Beiin
    """.format(df)
    try:
         smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtpserver')
         smtpObj.sendmail(sender , receivers, message)         
         print("Successfully sent email")
    except SMTPException:
         print ("Error: unable to send email")

    df = pd.read_csv(r'testcsv.csv')
    df.to_html('filename.html')
    f = codecs.open("filename.html",'r')
    df = HTML(f.read()) 

    sendEmail()
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it by adding with open('testcsv.html') as fp:
        html = fp.read()

Comment: Thank you Daniel... So glad to know that you fixed it